# netbeans freermarker plugin ERROR: The plugin Lexer to NetBeans Bridge is requested in implementation version

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, freemarker, netbeans-plugins

i'm using netbeans 8 and i have freeMarker as my template engine i downloaded this freeMarker plugin from this page http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52115/freemarker-netbeans-plugin and i try to installed but it gives me this error `The plugin Lexer to NetBeans Bridge is requested in implementation version` and the only option it gives me in the UI netbeans window is to presss cancel.

EDIT: one of the solution that dindt worked but i tried where the following

i found in a website was to download the whole project then build it with netbeans and copy the .nbm file generated.

THIS SOLUTIONS DONT WORK

I try the following solutions:

SOLution 1

```
1) downloading the project in a .zip file from this URL  https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/freemarker_NB_highlighting 
2) then i choose the option import project form a .zip file
3) then i hit the clean and build botton 
4) then i try to add the .nbm file generated in the cluster folder of the project 
but still it gives me the same error `The plugin Lexer to NetBeans Bridge is requested in implementation version 201207171143.`
```

Second solution

i foun this website http://michalcichon.blogspot.com/2014/02/freemarker-syntax-highlighting-in.html and it told me to  first install plugin called "`Lexer to NetBeans Bridge`" in this url http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-lexer-nbbridge/RELEASE71/ so i downloaded the .nbm file in that website, but when i try to install that Lexer to NetBeans Bridge plugin it tolds me that is already installed. Since i dont know how to check what plugins or modules/ide i have installed i checked the module.properties files in my C:Netbeans folder, in that file theres this line `lexer.nbbridge.dir=${netbeans.dest.dir}/ide` but i dont know if this means that is already installed or not.

in the author's page https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/syntax_coloring_for_freemarker one of the persons says that the solution 1 worked for him, but i tried it and it didn't worked for me. If it possible to solve this problem or should i give up

EDIT 2

i tried with this link to download a version that is suppsose to work with netbeans 8.0.2+ but now it gives me this error

```
    Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61completion to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61completion is requested in version 1.0.  The following plugin is affected:       Freemarker NetBeans Plugin
```

i tried downloading the whole zip and import it to netbeans and build it, later i copy the .nbm generated but if i do that it gives me the error:  `The plugin Lexer to NetBeans Bridge is requested in implementation version`,  i started looking a solution for this error

```
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61completion is requested in version 1.0.
```

and a website from 2009 says to add this plugin `http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5/uc/final/stable/modules/ide10/org-netbeans-modules-editor-deprecated-pre61completion.nbm`

when i add that plugins it gives me this error:

```
    Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61settings to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61settings is requested in version 1.0.  The following plugin is affected:       Editor Code Completion Prior 6.1 Separation 
Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.27 (release version 1) but only 3.49.2.22.43 (of release version different from 1) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       Editor Code Completion Prior 6.1 Separation
```

Answer (score 1):

> I solved it by: svn checkout https://java.net/projects/nb-api-samples/sources/api-samples/show/versions/7.2/m‌​isc/ftl?rev=333 Then opened that in NetBeans, built, and "Install/Reload module in IDE"

Above statements were right.

Here's how you should do it.

[Step 1]
Team -> Subversion -> Checkout

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbWh2.png
```

[Step 2]
use this Repository URL:

```
https://svn.java.net/svn/nb-api-samples~api-samples/versions/7.2/misc/ftl/?rev=333
```

check this image    `http://content.screencast.com/users/groundbreaker/folders/Jing/media/6fd82a20-bb11-449e-92cb-73af53fd2254/2015-05-22_0928.png`

[Step 3]
Click 'Finish"

```
http://content.screencast.com/users/groundbreaker/folders/Jing/media/b59faeab-ca38-4dad-aa56-1e62f1a42627/2015-05-22_0930.png
```

[Step 4]
Click 'Open Project'

```
http://content.screencast.com/users/groundbreaker/folders/Jing/media/e37efdcf-0a85-4746-bbca-e13d7bb59dfe/2015-05-22_0930.png
```

[Step 5]
You will now see the '**ftl**' Project

```
http://content.screencast.com/users/groundbreaker/folders/Jing/media/4ed866c8-4111-4db0-9057-9f0992fcb4e6/2015-05-22_0931.png
```

[Step 6]
Right Click -> Build -> Install/Reload in Development IDE

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjUco.png
```

Just copy paste open the URLs since I still cant post images and clickable links. Sorry for the hassle.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin requests a very specific version of NetBeans and this is incompatible to a non-matching version.

Please ask the author of the plugin to provide a version, which is compatible a official released NetBeans version!

Comment: by the comments on that plugin page it appears that is not for netbeans 8, but theres a person in the comments thats says this from 2014:

`Hi, I couldn't install - the above message is shown on installation.

I solved it by:

svn checkout https://java.net/projects/nb-api-samples/sources/api-samples/show/versions/7.2/misc/ftl?rev=333

Then opened that in NetBeans, built, and "Install/Reload module in IDE".` but i dont know how to do that can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: Yes I saw that too. Please file an issue at https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/freemarker_NB_highlighting/issues so that the original author can help you.

Comment: Try the newest version, which is claimed to be compatible to NB8.0.2 https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/freemarker_NB_highlighting/releases/tag/v1.0.1

Comment: i tried with that link, downloaded the .nbm and now it gives me this error 
`Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61completion to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre61completion is requested in version 1.0.  The following plugin is affected:       Freemarker NetBeans Plugin`

I Edited my question for more details